# TabBar does not show

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller

Tab bar controller storyboard:

[image]

This is how I call that tab bar:

```
let tabBar = TabBarController()
tabBar.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(tabBar, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But result:

[image]

What's wrong?

Comment: Presenting tabbar from ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are presenting the TabBarController(), but you have to instance using storyboard, because your view is created using storyboard.

```
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "filenamethatcontaineyourtabBar", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "storyboardIdOfYourTabBarController")
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is the first screen of your app, you don't need to present it. The first tab will appear automatically. You don't need a custom TabBarController class.

Comment: This is not the first screen. The first thing is to enter the account, then the tab bar should be displayed

Comment: Try making the tabbarVC the first screen, and present the log in VC on top of it?

Answer (score 0):

Having segues inside the tab bar controller won't show the tab bar. So don't add segues in the tab bar.